# Read fixed length file with implicit decimal point?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a data file like this:

```
foo12345
bar45612
```

I want to parse this into:

```
+----+-------+
|  id|    amt|
+----+-------+
| foo| 123.45|
| bar| 456.12|
+----+-------+
```

Which is to say, I need to select `df.value.substr(4,5).alias('amt')`, but I want the value to be interpreted as a five digit number where the last two digits are after the decimal point.

Surely there's a better way to do this than "divide by 100"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring, concat, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

#sample data
df = sc.parallelize([
    ['foo12345'],
    ['bar45612']]).toDF(["value"])

df = df.withColumn('id', substring('value',1,3)).\
    withColumn('amt', concat(substring('value', 4, 3),lit('.'),substring('value', 7, 2)).cast(DoubleType()))
df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+--------+---+------+
|   value| id|   amt|
+--------+---+------+
|foo12345|foo|123.45|
|bar45612|bar|456.12|
+--------+---+------+
```

Comment: @dmd did it help? Or you are looking for something else? Pls don't forget to let the community know about it :)

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the answer. That'll work, but it sure would be nice if this could be done more 'natively'.

Comment: I think more 'natively' would be to divide it by 100 after `cast` as `DoubleType()`